# Action Bar in Android Studio 1.5 Upgrade

Tags: android, xml

Can someone explain what is happening here. I load a blank Activity and two xml files are created in Android Studio; the content_main.xml, which contains all of my widgets, and activity_main.xml, which includes my contents file and looks like this:

[image]

I don't want to use this Toolbar so I delete it. Now the activity_main.xml file looks like this:

[image]

I still want to have an actionBar however. My manifest file, clearly references a theme in my styles folder:
[image]

And here is is the styles.xml file, which sets a theme for the Action Bar[image]:

How come, when I start the emulator, my action bar is missing? My main_activity extends AppCompatActivity. Any idea why this is happening?
[image]

Comment: have u explicitly set toolbar in activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are activity is overriding the `Application`'s theme and using the `NoActionBar` theme. Get rid of `android:theme` from the `<activity` tag

Change from

```
 <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

to

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll accept it in a few minutes.